# Trying to pull a price from an exchange using API

Tags: javascript, api

I'm still fairly new to javascript and I'm trying to use a sites API to pull the exchange rate from it to use on my site. Most of this stuff is going over my head so any help would be great, not even sure where to start This is my HTML code:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<body onload="startScript()">



<form name="frm">
Price: 
<input name="priceCAD" value="500" disabled><br><br>
Markup: 
<input name="percentage" value="" disabled><br><br>
Fiat: 
<input name="fiat"  value=""><br><br>
BTC: 
<input name="btc" value="" maxlength="6"><br><br>

<input type="button" onclick="calculater()" name="calculate" value="Calculate" />
<input type="button" name="clearBtn" value="Clear" onclick="clearValues()"><br>
<p id="error" value=""></p>
</form>
```

I want to be able to use this API: http://docs.bitfinex.com/?javascript#public-endpoints to pull the ticker information. From there I'm sure I can figure out how to manipulate it my needs. Any help at all would be great, the API code goes over my head so I'm not sure how to modify it or where even the output of a request is stored.

Comment: Hello @bgmrk welcome to stack overflow! Most API's will require some sort of key to allow access to their service. Have you got yours already?

Comment: Yes I have. It's more just in learning what the code is actually doing and then how to load the information into a variable/field.

Comment: Great! So you are already consuming the API? Area you using jQuery by the way?

Comment: What do you mean by consuming the API? I'm not familiar with jQuery...This is my first semi-serious programming project. I understand the fundamentals well, but anything beyond that I'm yet to experience.

Comment: Consuming an API basically means that you are being successful in requesting data from any address (end point) provided by the API. Can you share the javascript code you are using to consume the API?

Comment: In that case no I'm not consuming it yet. The only JS code i have in regards to getting the price comes from the API. I'm not sure how to integrate the API code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118936/discussion-between-n0m4d-and-bgmrk).

Answer (score 2):

You can make an AJAX call to retrieve the information from the API. Here is an example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd");// where "btcusd" is the symbol for which to retrieve the ticker
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); // at this point, "data" contains the API's response as a JavasScript Object.
    }
}
```

The API's response looks something like this:

```
{"mid":"599.41","bid":"599.32","ask":"599.5","last_price":"598.98","low":"595.0","high":"621.74","volume":"47549.93217106","timestamp":"1470157047.497089378"}
```

You should go through the API documentation to see what the different keys (mid, bid, ask, etc.) represent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I threw in some alerts and seems like the code is never entering the function to write to the var "data".

Comment: Not that I can tell, just that most likely the if statement isn't being executed. What do the numbers 4 and 200 refer to?

Comment: @bgmrk 4 is the ready state "DONE" and 200 is the HTTP response code for "OK"

Comment: After outputing the results, i get xhr.readystate = 1 and  xhr.status = 0. Also, why the 3 '=' in each if condition?

Comment: @bgmrk the `===` match both the variable's type and its value, in this case, this operator is not required, you can use `==` instead. If `xhr.readystate = 1 ` is the only update that you get it means that the request never finishes. I've just opened this link `https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd` in my browser and I get a `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` response, it worked when I've first tested it.

Comment: lol just my luck, I saw it working as well earlier. Alright I'll have to wait for that to sort itself out. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118950/discussion-between-bgmrk-and-titus).

Comment: I'm trying with another link that is working and it still isn't going through. Want to help me out via chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118950/discussion-between-bgmrk-and-titus